# losetup and mount create two entries in Nautilus for a floppy image

Tags: linux, mount, nautilus

I am referring to BrokenThorn's tutorial on OS development. Though it is for Windows, I learnt how to create a bootable floppy in Linux, mount it to transfer files and also boot off it.

After formatting the floppy image using `mkfs.vfat` and `dd`ing the boot loader onto it, I need to transfer the second stage binary to the "floppy". For this, I use `losetup` and link the image to `/dev/loop0`. This creates one entry in Nautilus (I'm using Ubuntu 13.04) in the left pane of devices.

Now, when I mount `/dev/loop0` using `mount`, it creates *another* entry in Nautilus, and I see the mounting/unmounting icon on *this* entry.

Why is is that two entries are created, when it is actually referring to the same device ? Shouldn't the mounting/unmounting icon appear on the entry that comes after doing `losetup` itself ?

Comment: bootable floppy? what is this 1993? does floppy mean something else?

Comment: I started with booting off a floppy image. I know thats old technology, but this was just to have an easy beginning, and I'll be soon moving to USB. However, what I have described occurs with any type of image.